# Does glyphosate herbicide break down into more toxic substances in the environment?

Tags: pesticides

I am being asked to sign [a petition](https://www.change.org/p/western-australian-minister-for-health-protect-our-children-s-health-from-pesticides-on-our-streets-parks-and-playgrounds) that claims

> The residues of glyphosate can stay in the environment for up to 174 days, often breaking down into more toxic substances.

Does [glyphosate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyphosate) (a.k.a. Roundup) break down into more toxic substances, in the environment?

Comment: Does "more toxic substances" mean "substances which are more toxic" or "more substances which are also toxic"?

Answer (score 5):

Glyphosate breaks down to aminomethylphosphonic acid.

Glyphosate and aminomethylphosphonic acid have about the same toxicity according to [PESTICIDE RESIDUES IN FOOD - 1997](http://www.inchem.org/documents/jmpr/jmpmono/v097pr04.htm):

> AMPA was no more toxic than glyphosate.  Similar effects were often found, except for the lesions in the salivary gland seen in the 90-day studies of
>       toxicity and carcinogenicity with glyphosate in mice nad [sic] rats from the
>       US national Toxicology Program and the cataracts induced by glyphosate
>       in a two-year toxicity study in rats.  Such effects were not seen in
>       other studies with glyphosate or AMPA.